# How old is the scripture Maya Samhita?

Tags: scripture, history, shilpa-shastras

[Maya Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_Samhita) is a scripture deals with shilpas.

When this scripture came into existence?

Comment: There is a text called Mayamatam मयमतं. Written by Mayasura , may be both are same somehow.

Comment: According to, Ravi Baghel, "There is no reliable date for the treatise which is known as “Maya Mata” or "Maya Samhita", but Maya the architect or builder is mentioned in Hindu texts dating to the fourth century BCE.": https://books.google.com/books?id=LVC-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq="maya+samhita"